# Is it possible to install BO 4.1 SP6 with Microsoft IIS 7.5

Tags: business-objects

Is it possible to install and run BO 4.1 SP6 with Microsoft IIS 7.5? I know Tomcat is bundled with BO and my employer doesn’t want to use it, WACS or any other web server. Has anybody been able to install BO 4.1 just on IIS (custom jobs as well)? The PAM states that BO 4.1 can utilize IIS only for Microsoft SharePoint (IOMS) . Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use IIS to integrate with SharePoint (ie show your BI documents in a SharePoint environment). However, you still need to have a Java application server (eg Tomcat, WebSphere, …).

TL;DR: no, you can't use IIS for that.

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate it!